# How do I prevent my grid from overlapping my page heading and avoid a scrollbar while resizing the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing CSS Transform Methods on CodePen. The following link will take you to the project I am having problems with: https://codepen.io/Gregorny/pen/abBqRLM?editors=1000

I've tried placing  inside of  and using the clearfix hack to clear items on both sides of the heading. I've tried setting the heading's position to relative and its display to block. So far, nothing I could think of trying or find anywhere else has worked.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1vw);
}

h1 {
  font-size: calc(40px + 1vw);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: -1px 0px lime, 0px -1px lime, 1px 0px lime, 0px 1px lime;
  margin-bottom: 5vw;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0px, 15vw));
  grid-auto-rows: 15vw;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  float: bottom;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15vw;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.translate:hover {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.scaleX:hover {
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
}

.scaleY:hover {
  transform: scaleY(0.8);
}

.scale:hover {
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}

.skewX:hover {
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>2-D Transform Methods:</h1>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="translate">Translate()</div>
      <div class="rotate">rotate()</div>
      <div class="scaleX">scaleX()</div>
      <div class="scaleY">scaleY()</div>
      <div class="scale">scale()</div>
      <div class="skewX">skewX()</div>
      <div class="skewY">skewY()</div>
      <div class="skew">skew()</div>
      <div class="matrix">matrix()</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe the use of vmin instead vw  and a few other reset could help https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOLvQzz

Comment: That looks a lot better. Just now learning what vmin and vmax are. Thanks! :)